# discoverSchema converts the column names to small case from camel case in loopback

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, loopback

disoverSchema function in loopback converts all the camel-cased column names to small-case. After reading a bit I found out its loopback-datasource-juggler which is responsible for this. Also, I read that its possible to preserve the naming strategy using name-mapper but have no idea how to use that. below is the piece of code where the table has camel-cased names but modelDef returned is having small-case names. Any help will be appreciated.
'

```
ds.discoverSchema(tableName, function(err, modelDef) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    }
```

Comment: Where did you come across the name-mapper? According to https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html there is no option to retain the naming strategy.

Comment: here the issue is was being discussed https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/issues/57 where @reymodfeng has given this link for the solution https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/lib/datasource.js#L1304

Comment: for the more detailed explanation of issue, you can refer this link https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/issues/1268